# Как указать честоту смены ноды в torrc

Tags: tor

Как указать частоту смены  ноды в файле torrc например на значение раз в 2 минуты?

Answer (score 1):

> **MaxCircuitDirtiness** [мин] — Tor может повторно использовать открытую
> цепочку для нового соединения, если она была создана меньше, чем [мин]
> назад (по умолчанию 10). Т.е. если Вы хотите, чтобы цепочки
> перестраивались чаще, установите здесь, допустим, 1.
>
> **NewCircuitPeriod** [сек] — как часто Tor должен проверять, необходимо ли сформировать
> новые цепочки (по умолчанию 30). Если Вы уменьшили значение
> предыдущего параметра, сократите и этот примерно до 10-15.
>
> https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual-dev.html.en